# Size Tolerances for 3D Model Components - Site Recommendation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm building a 3D model with individual components that fit together once printed.

I'm unsure of the best way to describe it, so I have included this image for illustration purposes:

[image: Model]

As you can see, this cuboid has a cap that slots into it once it's 3D printed. My question is, will they fit together if the edges are the same size (in this case 6mm and 24mm), or do I need to make the cap slightly smaller? if so, by how much? After all I don't want it to be loose, but I also need it to fit nicely.

I figure it may be fine if a bit of force is used as it's being printed in flexible plastic at Shapeways.

I'm not sure this is the correct site to post/ask on, so please advise if you know of a better place.

Comment: What are you using to make the model? [blender.se]?

Comment: Hi. I've made it in SketchUp as it's only basic shapes at the moment. It's exported and uploaded to shapeways as an obj :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what's exactly you want to ask, but there is two sites about "printing something":

- [Printing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61993/printing?referrer=lwkn96H1B8EyMTlTiZ8nng2):  Proposed Q&A site for professionals or enthusiasts in any sort of printing field, e.g. silkscreen, CMYK, offset, rotogravure, etc.
- [3D Printing and Rapid Prototyping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61436/3d-printing-and-rapid-prototyping?referrer=lwkn96H1B8HZNGDOhhHLaA2): Proposed Q&A site for makers involved in the latest trend of personal 3D printing on affordable open source platforms, and beyond.

There is something that deals with 3D/2D/XD digital creations:

- [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59918/digital-fabrication?referrer=2-Gr2QZjHRvk_arflz249A2):  Proposed Q&A site for professionals and enthusiasts who design, prototype and fabricate physical things using technologies *such as 3D printing*, scanning or cutting machines.

The three of them are in definition, sadly, but hey, it's a start! :D

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for posting. I'll check them out. :D